# Do you have to do duplicate gem installs for JRuby & MRI?

Tags: ruby, installation, jruby, rubygems

I have JRuby and Ruby (MRI) installed. It seems that I need to install gems twice - once for each of these platforms. Is this necessary or am I doing it wrong? After I installed the rails gem for MRI, should I have pointed JRuby to it, or was it necessary for me to also call: "jruby -S gem install rails"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set GEM_HOME you can share your gem installations.

Answer (score 4):

You need to install gems for each different install of ruby that you have.

Answer (score 1):

Some gems target specific platforms, e.g. Mongrel (there's a MRI one and a JRuby one).  Also, JRuby cannot use gems that have native extensions (i.e. C code) unless they use the FFI (which most do not - yet).

Personally I have separate gem repos for MRI and JRuby.  The little bit of extra hassle is worth the peace of mind when trying to track down a problem.

It's pretty easy to see what each repo has installed:

```
jruby -S gem list --local
```

vs.

```
gem list --local
```

You could even write a ruby script to sync one gem list to the other, but you'd have to be careful about platform specific gems....

Answer (score 1):

I hit this problem when creating my gem, [jimmy_jukebox](https://github.com/JamesLavin/jimmy_jukebox), but made my gem work with both.

First, JRuby doesn't handle `fork...exec` (and even replies incorrectly to `Process.respond_to?(:fork)`), so I had to `rescue NotImplementedError` and use `Spoon.spawnp` instead.

I then created (in my gem's /bin directory) paired executables -- `play_jukebox` and `jplay_jukebox`; and `load_jukebox` and `jload_jukebox` -- each with the correct shebang line (`/usr/bin/env ruby` or `/usr/bin/env jruby`).

I'd love to know a better way. But I'd rather handle everything within a single gem than maintain and distribute multiple gems.